# matplotlib quiver 3d error

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am running the quiver3d example given in the following tutorial
http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html

I am running python 'Python 2.7.6' on mac Yosemite with matplotlib  1.4.2

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.__version__
'1.4.2'
```

I am running the example given in matplotlib tutorial

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
x, y, z = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-0.8, 1, 0.2),
                      np.arange(-0.8, 1, 0.2),
                      np.arange(-0.8, 1, 0.8))

u = np.sin(np.pi * x) * np.cos(np.pi * y) * np.cos(np.pi * z)
v = -np.cos(np.pi * x) * np.sin(np.pi * y) * np.cos(np.pi * z)
w = (np.sqrt(2.0 / 3.0) * np.cos(np.pi * x) * np.cos(np.pi * y) *  np.sin(np.pi * z))

ax.quiver(x, y, z, u, v, w, length=0.1)

plt.show()
```

but getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try.py", line 16, in <module>
    ax.quiver(x, y, z, u, v, w, length=0.1)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 4179, in quiver
    q = mquiver.Quiver(self, *args, **kw)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/quiver.py", line 417, in __init__
    X, Y, U, V, C = _parse_args(*args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/quiver.py", line 379, in _parse_args
    nr, nc = U.shape
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

BTW ax is an Axes3D I verified it using `isinstance(ax, axes3d.Axes3d)` and it returned True. Plus I verified if Axes3d definition contains quiver method and apparently it doesn't and it is using Axes quiver method instead. Now I don't know if it must have quiver definition or not

Comment: I can't reproduce.  Given that you are on a mac and OSX's path handling is pathological I suspect you have more than one version of mpl installed and you are seeing a mix of files between the two (or more).

Comment: If axes3d does not have the quiver definition it will fallback to the method of the class it inherits, which is what is causing the problem. Try "uninstalling" I. E. Deleting matplotlib and then grab it again.

Answer (score 0):

`ax` needs to be an `axes3d` object - at the moment it's just a regular `axes` object, and so the call to `ax.quiver` is calling the 2D routine, which has a different function signature. If you look at those lines in the source you'll see that line 417 of `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/quiver.py` is trying to unpack all of your arguments, `x,y,z,u,v,w` - 6 args, into just 5 variables.

I'm not sure why, and can't check at the moment, but for some reason `fig.gca(projection="3d")` is *not* giving you an `axes3d` object, and so the 2D version of quiver is being caleld instead of the 3D one.

Doing a little more digging, `fig.gca(...)` just calls `fig.add_subplot(1,1,1,**kwargs)` if there's no axes object on the stack. Is this a complete program? or are you doing this after doing some other stuff in the same program?

You could try replacing the `gca` call with `add_subplot(1,1,1,projection='3d')` - that does not query the stack, so it won't matter if you have other stuff there already.

Comment: actually It's an axes3d instance and not an axes I verified it before posting the question using isinstance(ax, axes3d.Axes3D) and it returned True.
the thing is that in my cases Axes3D doesn't contain the quiver definition and it is rather using Axes.quiver instead

Comment: Try deleting the version of mpl that the error points to and running it again.

Comment: I did delete the version and reinstalled matplotlib using pip2 install matplotlib but still the same problem occurring ...

Comment: when you import matplotlib, can you print the location (`print matplotlib.__file__` should work). Then open up the source for `axes3d` and see if it has the quiver method.

Comment: print matplotlib.__file__ is /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__ while axe3d is in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py
and yes the Definition of quiver is in axes3d but I'm afraid it is not used on mac.
I tried the same verison on windows and all works fine ...

Comment: Could you add some print statements into the `axes3d` class, to exactly what the functions being called are?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced exactly the same problem on Linux, python 2.7 and matplotlib older than 1.3.
After having installed the newest stable matplotlib from source and it still didn't work.
Only after purging the old matplotlib files it worked.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: @o11c I disagree. While I can't verify if this answer actually fixes the OP's problem, he clearly gives a possible solution with `Only after purging the old matplotlib files it worked`